# Calling a function in csharp script class in assets folder from a csharp script class from Android Plugins folder in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, callback

I am able to call functions from two different classes in my assets folder in my unity setup. I can also access functions of script files from my plugin folder but NOT vice versa. For example

**Below is a class from my Assets folder for a game object Spinning Cube**

The script below defines the rotation of the cube

```
public class SpinningCube : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float m_Speed = 20f;

    private Vector3 m_RotationDirection = Vector3.up;

    public Texture btnTexture;

    public void ToggleRotationDirection()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Toggling rotation direction");            

        if (m_RotationDirection == Vector3.up) 
        { 
            MyPlugin.doSomething();    
            m_RotationDirection = Vector3.down;
        }
        else 
        {
            MyPlugin.doSomethingElse();  
            m_RotationDirection = Vector3.up;
        }
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        transform.Rotate(m_RotationDirection * Time.deltaTime * m_Speed);
    }

}
```

Functions in my MyPlugin class in plugins > Android folder are successfully called from Spinning cube.

**But** I can't seem to call a function in SpinningCube class from MyPlugin Class.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace My.Plugins {

    public class MyPlugin {
        public static void doSomething () {
            //doing something

        }

        public static void doSomethingElse () {
            //doing something else
        }


    }

}
```

When I try to access a function in SpinningCube class from MyPlugin file:

It says

> "SpinningCube does not exist in the current context."

Any Pointers are welcome.

I want to do this to code for **call backs.**

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously access the `MyPlugin` class methods because they're `static`, that means they can be accessed without the need of a reference to an instance of the class.

In order to access the `ToggleRotationDirection` method from `MyPlugin`, you need a reference to the `SpinningCube` class.

Add this:

```
public SpinningCube spinningCube;
```

in the `MyPlugin` class, then assign to it in the Inspector the game object which has the `SpinningCube` script.

After that, you'll be able to call the method using `spinningCube.ToggleRotationDirection();`